# Removing up down arrows from Lightweight Picker

Tags: codenameone

I've spotted two arrows in the Lightweight `Pickers`, they seem to be used to go from a field to another.

This behavior is really buggy in my editor and cause encoding errors from some customers. Is there a way to hide/remove them ? If possible in the whole app ?

<s>I've tried to override the `Picker` and set the return of `isEditable` to `false`, as it seemed to control the adding of those arrows, but that has done nothing.</s>

Thanks in advance !

EDIT: In this precise case, I'm using a lightweight `Picker` with type `PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS`, but I'd like to control this behavior on all lightweight `Pickers`.

The picker is instanciated from a `PickerComponent` with the `static createStrings` method.

Here is the screenshot of this specific picker and the buttons I want to get rid of are within the red rectangle :

[image: String picker]

EDIT 2 : Aftert some code analysis, I've found those arrows are shown if the `TabIterator` of the enclosing `Form` return previous and next components for this picker. I really don't understand how I dreamed that isEditable was controlling this !

It's possible to override the `getTabIterator` of the `Form`, but the constructor of `TabIterator` (nested class of `Form`) is `private`, so unreachable in our classes, and we need it because there no `null` check on the `TabIterator` instance when it's called, so we can't return `null`.

I've tried forcing the parameter of the `getTabIterator` to `null`, but the `getNext` and `getPrevious` methods of `TabIterator` return `null` only if the component is `null` and the component `List` (passed as second arg of the `TabIterator` constructor) is empty. But as the constructor is `private`, the `List` is never empty as it's filled by the `getTabIterator`.

Dead end ?

Comment: A screenshot would help...

Comment: And the type of picker you used on which OS/device. Code you used etc.

Comment: I've added some details and a screenshot, I'm using those pickers on iOS, Android and the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly designed for paging between multiple entry fields seamlessly. It seems this isn't pluggable as it should be. You should probably file an RFE so we can provide a way to customize this.

You can file an RFE in the issue tracker here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/

A possible workaround might be invoking `remove()` over the tab iterator until it's empty.

Comment: Using remove on the `TabIterator` until empty is laggy, but would work, the best workaround (which is the right way to disable the arrows according to Steve) is to use the component selector and set all preffered tab indexes to -1. The code to do it quick is : `ComponentSelector.select("*", form).each(c-> c.setPreferredTabIndex(-1));`. With all tabIndex to -1, the `TabIterator` is empty and the arrows are gone.